# I want to Change multiple to colors on mouse click in an individual cell in a table

Tags: html, css

My goal is to cycle through the colors; White, Green, Yellow, and Red in individual table cells on a mouse click. I'm trying to use a simple online assessment of various elements and send screenshots to a mentor. This is the code I used for two colors (White, Green).

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("td");

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  cells[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.className = this.className == "white" ? "green" : "white";
  });
}
```

```css
.green {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.white {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

#sales-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="sales-list">
  <tr>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 1</td>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 2</td>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="white">Row 2 Col 1</td>
    <td class="white">Row 2 Col 2</td>
    <td class="white">Row 2 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="white">Row 3 Col 1</td>
    <td class="white">Row 3 Col 2</td>
    <td class="white">Row 3 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a data-* attribute, and style accordingly.

Just like **Mister Jojo**, I would just add an event listener to the whole table, and get the target directly from the event argument, by using {target}.

Get the dataset.class from the td, increase it by one, and if it's higher than the number of colors you want, you set the new data-class as to `1`.

I also added `td` to share the same styling as `td[data-class="1"]`, so you don't need to add *data-class="1"* to all `td`s.

Less code. More functionality.

```js
document.getElementById('sales-list')
.addEventListener('click', changeColorOnCell);

function changeColorOnCell({target}) {
  const NUMBER_OF_COLORS = 4,
        FIRST_COLOR = 1;

  if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
    let newClass = Number(target.dataset.class || FIRST_COLOR) + 1;
    target.dataset.class = (newClass > NUMBER_OF_COLORS) ? FIRST_COLOR : newClass;
  }
}
```

```css
#sales-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

td, td[data-class="1"] { background-color: white; }
td[data-class="2"]     { background-color: green; }
td[data-class="3"]     { background-color: yellow; }
td[data-class="4"]     { background-color: red; }

td[data-class="2"],
td[data-class="4"] {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="sales-list">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2 Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 2 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3 Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 3 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Rickard!

Answer (score 2):

Store the colors in an array and get the index of the class on click, then get the class at the next index and assign it to the `className`.

Do remember to perform a check to see whether the color is the last item of the array, and if so, reset the index back to `0`.

```js
var colors = ['white', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("td");

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  cells[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var i = colors.indexOf(this.className);
    this.className = colors[i == colors.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1];
  });
}
```

```css
.green {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.white {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

#sales-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="sales-list">
    <tr>
      <td class="white">Row 1 Col 1</td>
      <td class="white">Row 1 Col 2</td>
      <td class="white">Row 1 Col 3</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="white">Row 2 Col 1</td>
      <td class="white">Row 2 Col 2</td>
      <td class="white">Row 2 Col 3</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="white">Row 3 Col 1</td>
      <td class="white">Row 3 Col 2</td>
      <td class="white">Row 3 Col 3</td>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Spectric!

Comment: @ChuckDebWood No problem. If it answers your question, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use an event delegation -for all td

```js
const Colors = ['white', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']

document.querySelector('#sales-list').onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('td')) return
  let idx = (Colors.indexOf(target.className) +1) %4
  target.className = Colors[idx]
  }
```

```css
.green  { background: green;  color: white; }
.white  { background: white;  color: black; }
.yellow { background: yellow; color: black; }
.red    { background: red;    color: black; }

table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
td {
  padding  : .2em .8em;
  border   : 1px solid darkblue;
  cursor   : pointer;
  }
```

```html
<table id="sales-list">
  <tr>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 1</td>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 2</td>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="white">Row 2 Col 1</td>
    <td class="white">Row 2 Col 2</td>
    <td class="white">Row 2 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="white">Row 3 Col 1</td>
    <td class="white">Row 3 Col 2</td>
    <td class="white">Row 3 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Mister Jojo!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest treating the table as an DOM object. See below traversing the rows/columns and toggling accordingly. If you'd like to tinker more with the methods [here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/LYPKZWQ). (Oh and didn't know if you meant cycle by cell or color in general sooo it's just cycling the colors.)

```js
const table = document.getElementById('sales-list'),
      colors = ['white', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
      
let colorIndex = 0;

for (let i = 0, x = table.rows.length; i < x; i++) {
  for (let c = 0, e = table.rows[i].cells.length; c < e; c++) {
    table.rows[i].cells[c].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       let currentBg = table.rows[i].cells[c];
       currentBg.className = colors[colorIndex];
       colorIndex >= (colors.length-1) ? colorIndex = 0 : colorIndex++;  
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.green { background: green; color: white; }
.white { background: white; color: black; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; color: black; }
.red { background-color: red; color: white; }

#sales-list { border: 1px solid black;}
td { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table id="sales-list">
  <tr>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 1</td>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 2</td>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="white">Row 2 Col 1</td>
     <td class="white">Row 2 Col 2</td>
     <td class="white">Row 2 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="white">Row 3 Col 1</td>
     <td class="white">Row 3 Col 2</td>
     <td class="white">Row 3 Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Chris W.!